# Undefined citations but citekey matches bibliography

Tags: citing, natbib

I know that this is a recurring issue but I have been entirely unable to find out what's going on. I keep getting undefined citations, my bib file

```
@article{Yao_Sensitivity_2014,
title = {Sensitivity of Photoacoustic Microscopy},
volume = {2},
issn = {2213-5979},
url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2213597914000111},
doi = {10.1016/j.pacs.2014.04.002},
abstract = {},
number = {2},
journaltitle = {Photoacoustics},
shortjournal = {Photoacoustics},
urldate = {2016-10-19},
date = {2014-06},
pages = {87--101},
keywords = {Absorption contrast,Contrast agents,Detection sensitivity,Early 
cancer detection,Ultrasonic transducer,photoacoustic microscopy},
author = {Yao, Junjie and Wang, Lihong V.},
file = {C:\\Users\\User\\Zotero\\storage\\6J88ECWR\\Yao and Wang - 2014 - 
Sensitivity of photoacoustic 
microscopy.pdf;C:\\Users\\USer\\Zotero\\storage\\C842F6SK\\Yao and Wang - 
2014 
- Sensitivity of photoacoustic microscopy.pdf;C:\\Users\\USer\\Zotero\\storage\\773V75IP\\S2213597914000111.html;C:\\Users\\USer\\Zotero\\storage\\D89STV9S\\S2213597914000111.html;C:\\Users\\USer\\Zotero\\storage\\XGG74R6X\\S2213597914000111.html}
}
```

and my MWE looks like

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[%
 reprint,%
%secnumarabic,%
 amssymb, amsmath,%
 aip,apl,%
%groupedaddress,%
%frontmatterverbose,
]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{docs}%
\usepackage{bm}%
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}%
%\nofiles
\expandafter\ifx\csname package@font\endcsname\relax\else
\expandafter\expandafter
\expandafter\usepackage
\expandafter\expandafter
 \expandafter{\csname package@font\endcsname}%
\fi
\hyphenation{title}
\begin{document}

\title{Author's Guide to AIP Substyles for \revtex~4.1}%

\author{AIP Journal Program}%
\email{tex@aip.org}
\affiliation{American Institute of Physics\\Suite 1NO1, 2 Huntington 
Quadrangle\\Melville, New York 11747-4502, USA}%

\date{March 2010}%
\revised{August 2010}%

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}


\cite{Yao_Sensitivity_2014}
\citep{yao_sensitivity_2014}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Exported Items}


\end{document}
```

but I keep getting that both my citations are undefined. Is this a problem with my bib file or something else?

Comment: Try removing the space from the filename of the `.bib` file (look in the `.blg` file, you might find an error complaining about that space). Then use only the citation with the correct case, as samcarter mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `\citep{yao_sensitivity_2014}` with `\citep{Yao_sensitivity_2014}`